# Estimation of std error using sample std dev. will result in diff. sample statistic distribution for diff. samples. Won't this affect our decision?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, standard-deviation, standard-error, p-value

During hypothesis testing (say, comparison of ***sample mean*** to a hypothesised ***population mean***), we calculate p-value using ***sample mean*** distribution. For constructing this ***sample mean*** distribution, we need:

1. mean of the ***sample mean***'s (or mean of the population):  This we get from our hypothesis.
2. std error of the ***sample mean***'s:  This equals to ***population std dev/sqrt(sample size)*** . Since we do not know the ***population std dev***, we use the ***sample std dev.*** as an estimate of ***population std dev.***

Now, the doubt is, for different samples, we will have different ***sample std dev***'s, so we will end up with different ***sample mean*** distributions. Hence the p-value shouldn't be necessarily comparable. Can someone please help and explain what I am missing here?